# compiling error core.c in mapcache with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mapserver

When installing mapcache in cygwin, `make` produced:

```
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c: In function ‘mapcache_prefetch_tiles’:
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c:81:3: error: unknown type name ‘apr_thread_t’
   apr_thread_t **threads;
   ^
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c:82:3: error: unknown type name ‘apr_threadattr_t’
   apr_threadattr_t *thread_attrs;
   ^
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c:83:7: warning: unused variable ‘nthreads’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int nthreads;
       ^
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c:82:21: warning: unused variable ‘thread_attrs’ [-Wunused-variable]
   apr_threadattr_t *thread_attrs;
                     ^
/opt/mapcache/mapcache-rel-1-2-1/lib/core.c:81:18: warning: unused variable ‘threads’ [-Wunused-variable]
   apr_thread_t **threads;
                  ^
```

I searched for some hints about this error but didn't find anything. Looking for `apr_thread_t` and cywgin, I found some pages pointing to an error with apache, but not really sure if apache has something to do here.

Any ideas about this please? what is the mapcache forum? is there any? thanks for any hints on this,

Answer (score 1):

Updating the this answer based on post from the mapserver list by the developer of mapcache:

From http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/apr-dev/201209.mbox/%3C4994179EC7ED6843AAB0A30A1639E7F825143612EF@DGEX2V.dg.deltagroup.com%3E it would seem that threads are not supported by Apr on cygwin. Currently mapcache does not support unthreaded environments so there's nothing you can do without hacking the mapcache codebase. I believe the change would not be very extensive as the source WMS fetches only need to be sequentialized instead of parralelized in core.c

Comment: `apr` packages are installed and tried also `-DWITH_APACHE=0`, but the same error. I used `cmake .. -DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 -DWITH_SQLITE=0 -DWITH_MAPSERVER=1 -DMAPSERVER_LIBRARY="/opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1/build/libmapserver.dll.a" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/mapserver/mapserver-6.4.1;" -DWITH_APACHE=0 -DWITH_VERSION_STRING=0 -DWITH_FCGI=0`, so no idea, how can I know if `apr` is really the problem?

Comment: ok, Well I would ask this question on the mapserver list as the developer of this module monitors that list and I'm not sure he watches stackoverflow.

Comment: It is possible that the cygwin apr package is just too old of a version.

Comment: thanks Stephen, I read Andy's answer in the mapserver forum, I also read your post, thanks for that, I think we should follow the discussion there and post the solution here, here is the link: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/compiling-error-core-c-in-mapcache-with-cygwin-td5179881.html#a5180356